# ImportJSON for Google Sheets Can't Handle File WIthout Properties?

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to pull historical pricing data from CoinGecko's free API to use in a Google Sheet. It presents OHLC numbers in the following format:

```
[
   [1589155200000,0.05129,0.05129,0.047632,0.047632],
   [1589500800000,0.047784,0.052329,0.047784,0.052329],
   [1589846400000,0.049656,0.053302,0.049656,0.053302],
   ...
]
```

As you can see, this isn't typical JSON format since there are no property names. So that everyone is on the same page, for this data the properties of each subarray in order are Time (in UNIX epoch format), Open Price, High Price, Low Price, and Close Price.

I'm using the [ImportJSON code found here](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs) to try and pull this data, but it does not work. Instead of putting each subarray into a separate row, split into columns for the 5 properties, it prints everything out into a single cell like so:

```
1589155200000,0.05129,0.05129,0.047632,0.047632,1589500800000,0.047784,0.052329,0.047784,0.052329,15898 6400000,0.049656,0.053302,0.049656,0.053302,...
```

This is incredibly unhelpful. I'm trying to avoid using a paid API add-on since I really don't want to have to pay the frankly exorbitant fees they want to charge, but I can't figure out a way to get ImportJSON to play nicely with this data. Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's simplier : your datas are in an array structure : I put

```
[
   [1589155200000,0.05129,0.05129,0.047632,0.047632],
   [1589500800000,0.047784,0.052329,0.047784,0.052329],
   [1589846400000,0.049656,0.053302,0.049656,0.053302]
]
```

in A1, and I get the individual values by this simplier way :

```
function myArray(){
  var f = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var result = eval(f.getRange('A1').getValue());
  f.getRange(2,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result)
}
```